# Anchor text that triggers onClick of a different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a page where content is spread over several tabs. The user clicks each tab (anchor inside an `<li>`) in order to switch. I would like to anchor some other text to trigger the onClick of a tab in order to also switch the content.

Is this possible with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Yes, but without seeing your representative code it's impossible to provide anything other than general advice, which is not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can invoke a click event on another element using jQuery's .click();

```
<a href="javascript:$('#tablink').click()">Trigger tab click</a>
```

Where #tablink is the ID of the tab you want to trigger.

More info: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with Jquery which is simple and easy to use. what you can actually do is that , you can attach a event eg., `click` to a event handler, which would do the stuff like loading appropriate content on to your current tab.

well this can be achieved by attaching the event to the event handler using a selector. `.on()` function is used as per the latest `jquery lib`  although `.click()` also would work but its advisable to use `.on()` as it handles event delegation as well.

**Example:**

```
$( ".tab a" ).on( "click", function() {
     // load the appropriate content to the current clicked tab
});
```

**REF:**
http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Jsfiddle to play with :**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/h4JXs/1732/

Happy Coding :)